# Unable to use material-ui withStyles() with react-beautiful-dnd

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am able to reproduce the error in a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/qljxqnx8w9).
These are the errors I'm seeing:

Local:

```
Warning: Stateless function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail.

Check the render method of `WithStyles(Card)`.
    in Card (created by WithStyles(Card))
    in WithStyles(Card) (at Todo.js:112)
```

Local and [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/qljxqnx8w9):

```
Invariant failed: Cannot get draggable ref from drag handle
```

From my googling, it seems that I can't use `withStyles` since it's a stateless functional component. If that's the case, what's the alternative?  I would like to continue using the benefits of the `withStyle` wrapper (which is injecting the mui theme and stylesheet into the component).

Please be aware that I simplified my code for the sandbox for the sake of clarity (I removed redux for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to wrap the `Card` component in a `div`.  Here is the [sandbox with a working solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/xr7ox6rjzz)

Comment: Works great to wrap Material UI components in divs